# Google charts show extra X axis value if setting Date format

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Line Chart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script>
      function createLineGraph(id,title) {
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
              var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
              data.addColumn('date', 'X(Years)')
              // data.addColumn('number', 'X(Years)')
              data.addColumn('number', 'Y')
              data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'})
              data.addColumn('number', 'Y1')
              data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'})

              data.addRows([
                [new Date('2021-02-03'), 2, null,5,null],
                [new Date('2021-02-04'), 3, null,15,null],
                [new Date('2021-02-05'), 4, null,25,null],
                [new Date('2021-02-06'), 5, '5',12,'12']
              ]);

              // data.addRows([
              //   [5, 2, null,5,null],
              //   [6, 3, null,15,null],
              //   [6, 4, null,25,null],
              //   [12, 5, '5',12,'12']
              // ]);

              var options = {
                  title: title,
                  hAxis: {
                     format: 'MMM yy' // Format the dates as month and year
                  },
                  titleTextStyle: {
                      fontSize: 18,
                      bold: true,
                      textAlign: 'center'
                  },
                  titlePosition: 'none',
                  curveType: 'none',
                  legend: { position: 'none' },
                  pointSize:0,
                  displayLegendValues:false,
                  annotations: {
                    stem: {
                      color: 'transparent'
                    },
                    alwaysOutside: false,
                    textStyle: {
                        fontSize: 12,
                        color: '#000',
                        auraColor: 'none'
                    }
                  }
              };

              var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(id));
              chart.draw(data, options);
        } 
      }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">      
      createLineGraph('chart_div','Support')
      createLineGraph('chart_div1','Resistance')
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <h4>Support</h4>          
          <div id="chart_div"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <h4>Resistance </h4>          
          <div id="chart_div1"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Upon setting:

```
hAxis: {
                     format: 'MMM yy' // Format the dates as month and year
                  },
```

It shows an extra X-axis value on the left:

[image]

But when I remove it shows correct entires but wrong format of first entry:

[image]

Comment: if your date format does not include day, then the x-axis labels will repeat. if you don't include a format, google will fit whatever it can. so, use a format that includes day, or you can manually set the x-axis labels / ticks to prevent them from repeating, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60674188/5090771).

Comment: @WhiteHat I did include the day as you can see in the 2nd image. it convert Feb 3 to 6 AM itself

Comment: providing your own ticks is the way to go